# how can I feed the hash value from digest.rdf to ansible get_url?

Tags: ansible

For example [here](https://imagemagick.org/archive/binaries/digest.rdf) we have a list of digests. I wonder is there simple way to generate a checksum value for get_url out of it.

Is there any easy way to parse rdf into dictionary? or maybe we can query the rdf path like xml?

### update

I just realized the rdf is xml with some namespace. I can query it in program language like python's lxml as following:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse("/tmp/digest.rdf")
ns = root.getroot().nsmap
root.xpath('/rdf:RDF/digest:Content[@rdf:about="magick"]/digest:sha256/text()', namespaces=ns)[0]
```

But I cannot get this to work in ansible:

1. I have to explicitly set the namespaces parameter.
2. I cannot use `/text()` to let it return just a text. without it, the returned matches value is a list of dict.

```
ansible localhost -m xml -a 'path=/tmp/digest.rdf xpath=/rdf:RDF/digest:Content[@rdf:about="magick"]/digest:sha256/text() print_match=yes' -i inventory
PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [xml] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  module_stderr: |-
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 107, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 99, in _ansiballz_main
      File "<stdin>", line 47, in invoke_module
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 224, in run_module
        return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
        _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_zgisyqdh/ansible_xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py", line 989, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_zgisyqdh/ansible_xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py", line 943, in main
      File "/tmp/ansible_xml_payload_zgisyqdh/ansible_xml_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/general/plugins/modules/xml.py", line 399, in do_print_match
      File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2311, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath
      File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 357, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__
      File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
    lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
  module_stdout: ''
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1
```

Is there anyway to let it automatically get the nsmap like lxml?